Error Running an Old Angular 8 Project on Node.js v18
I recently downloaded an old Angular 8 project from GitHub and tried to run it locally. After running npm install to install the required dependencies, I attempted to start the project using ng serve. However, I encountered the following error message:
C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient>ng serve
10% building 3/3 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/webpack-dev-server/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
10% building 3/4 modules 1 active ...pack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:69
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:412:16)
    at C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:444:10
    at C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:320:13
    at C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
    at processResource (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:292:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:438:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:702:10)
    at C:\Users\Fozle Rabbi\Desktop\Folder GIt\AngularFuelSensor\FuelSensorClient\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:944:14 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.20.3

It seems to be related to the cryptography libraries in Node.js (ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED). I am currently using Node.js v18.20.3. I suspect that the project is not compatible with this version of Node.js because it was built with Angular 8, which might be using older versions of Webpack or other libraries.
Steps I took:

Downloaded the project from GitHub.
Run npm install.
Attempted to run the project with ng serve.

My Question:

Is there a way to resolve this error while still using Node.js v18?
Alternatively, should I downgrade Node.js to an earlier version to match the compatibility of the Angular 8 project? If so, which version would work best?

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Angular 8 doesn't support NodeJS v18, see the compatibility table. You need to install NodeJS ^10.9.0 to run an Angular 8 project.
To give a bit more context: Angular supports major releases for 18 months, according to their docs. Angular v8 was released back in 2019 and is well outside the support window. With that that policy in place, they cannot ensure compatibility of old Angular versions with newer NodeJS versions.
